# PHP - using labels instead of indexes in an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fetching a row from a database using something like this

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

This example shows accessing $row using an index, like $row[0], but this is a path to error. I would like to do it like $row['id'] or $row['email']... how is that possible?

Comment: Use either PDO or MySQLi

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of mysql_fetch_row:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

(That gives you the "associative array", so that you can fetch columns by their name.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_row()`